# principles of fingerprinting

Tags: signature

What are the principles of fingerprinting.

For example, I could take a hash of an object, which means that if exactly the same digital object re-appears I can recognize it (collisions excepted).  However, to improve robustness, I would like to recognize any slightly altered version of a photograph (say re-sized or slightly clipped or rotated).  Similarly with biometrics, such as real "fingerprints", each time we measure, we will get a different image, but we will hopefully produce a digital fingerprint signature that matches this and only this real-life fingerprint - in theory anyway!

What are the principles underlying "fingerprinting" in general?  What makes a good "fingerprinting" algorithm?